# Report for number of events attended by each person

Tags: reports, custom-reports

I would like a report that lists the number of events attended by (or registered by) each participant.  This seems like something that a lot of organizations would find useful, yet I can't seem to find anything even close to this that I could customize into what I'm looking for.  Am I missing something, or is there no such report in existence.  If not, any suggestions.
Thanks,
Rick

Comment: if you are on Drupal then Views and 'aggregation' could quickly give you the count of events each contact has attended, if that is what you want and if you can't get it easily via civi report

Comment: Thanks, but I am not on Drupal.

Answer (score 3):

I think you can get what you want with the "Event Participants Report" (under the Events > Event Reports Menu). In the "Sorting" tab, just tick the box for "Section Header / Group By" against "Last Name, First Name". You use the "Filters" tab to restrict to a particular time period, set of events etc.

In general if I can't do something off the shelf in CiviCRM then I export a search result or report to Excel and manipulate it there. A lot easier than writing a new report. In this case I would have used the Subtotal function in Excel if I couldn't have done it within CiviCRM.

Comment: Mick, Thanks for that.  Yes, I have frequently imported stuff into Excel, and then manipulated it from there, but I really want to learn how to use the Civi Reports more...

Comment: So I did what you said, and I see a report that lists every participant.  Next to each one's name is the number of events they attended in parenthesis.  That is getting me close, but I am missing something.  I would like to be able to sort on the number of events, but since the total number of events is not a data field, I don't know how to do that.  Am I missing something?

Comment: I don't think you would be able to do that in the CiviCRM report - as you say it only allows sorting by the data fields from the participant record. I think the only way to do this is the export to Excel (which gets the report without the subtotals, use the Excel subtotal tool and then manipulate it a bit (I played a bit filtering out blanks in the first column then sorting by the second column, but you probably need to do a bit more that to be able to use it).